# How to retrieve machine IP adress via SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I wanted to know if we can retrieve IPAddresses of *any* machine (can be local or remote) via Microsoft SQL Stored Procedure WITHOUT using INSERT EXECUTE.

Answer (score 2):

All you need as a starting point is:

```
SELECT client_net_address, local_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Obviously, it needs a bit more work but [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509%28SQL.90%29.aspx) has both server and client IP addresses.

Edit:

I suggest you look at CLR code fi you want to gather information that SQL Server simply does not have within your restrictions.

Any pure T-SQL solution requires running a stored proc such as `xp_cmdshell` which requires INSERT EXEC.

A parameterised stored proc would have to be custom extended one to avoid INSERT EXEC.

Comment: This seems to give IP address of only machines that are accessing the particular SQL instance. I wanted to say "any machine" on the network which may not be necessarily accessing the SQL server (similar to ping machine name).

Comment: I thought of CLR option. However I need to support SQL 2000 too. Hence it is out of question. Also openrowset was a possible workaround.

Comment: Don't know how you'd use openrowset